# Is it possible to set up type-hinting based on variable / function naming?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a custom python framework that recursively explores a project and runs functions with a pre-defined function naming scheme (kind of like how pytest runs functions that are prefixed with "test").

When I create one of these functions that the framework is going to call, I am required to define the function with 1 parameter.  This parameter specifies an object that the framework will pass me when it calls my function.

For the sake of simplicity, let's call this argument 'banana' and assume that it's type is 'Banana' which was instantiated when the framework was initialized.  The framework collects all of functions that it knows it needs to run, and then calls them sequentially one-by-one and passes each of them this global 'banana' object.

My question is:  Is there any way for me to provide type-hinting for this parameter in the scripts wherein these functions are defined?

Example:

```
# The framework will search our project and run any function that is prefixed with 'fruit'

def fruit_MyFunction1(banana):
    """
    @param banana: Provided by the framework
    """

    # Ideally, I would have type hinting here, and Python would know that 'banana'
    # is of type [Banana] and provide me a list of relevant methods / parameters
    banana.do_something()

def fruit_MyFunction2(banana):
    """
    @param banana: Provided by the framework
    """

    print banana.colour
```

I'm aware of .pyi files, and I'm wondering if I can scheme something where **any** function that is prefixed with 'fruit' will assume that the first argument is a [Banana] object and provide type hinting accordingly.

**Note:**  I don't know what the function names will be until the framework identifies them at runtime.  So I can't simply define "fruit_MyFunction1" and "fruit_MyFunction2" (as in the above example) in a .pyi file, because the names are arbitrary...all I know is that some functions will have a specific prefix, and those are the ones that I know will have the required function signature.